# Add a method to an Object's ActiverecordRelation

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model `School` with a `has_many` relationship with `PerformanceStats`.

I find myself often writing this code in console and throughout some rake tasks.

```
School.where(city: "Chicago").joins(:performance_stats).where(performance_stats: {year: "1819"}.where.not(performance_stats: {gr3_score: nil})
```

I though perhaps I could shorten this by including a method on a School's ActiveRecord Relation, so I could do something like:

```
School.where(city: "Chicago").pstatjoin("1819","gr_score",nil)

def pstatjoin(year,x,y)
 x.to_sym
 self.joins(:performance_stats).where(performance_stats: {year: year}.where.not(performance_stats: {x => y})
end
```

But I'm not sure where to put this code.

I tried this in the SchoolsHelper Module:

```
Module SchoolHelper
  Class School
    def pstatjoin(year,x,y)
     x = x.to_sym
     self.joins(:performance_stats).where(performance_stats: {year: year}.where.not(performance_stats: {x => y})
    end
  end
end
```

and I included the module in the Schools Model

```
include SchoolsHelper
```

but this resulted in `undefined method 'pj' for #<School::ActiveRecord_Relation:hexidecimal>)`

Is there a way to do this without adding code that will apply to every ActiveRecord_Relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good approach/fit for this problem are definitely [scopes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope), with a scope you can save some time and comply with the DRY principle, so you can define a scope within your `School` model as below:

```rb
scope :my_awesome_scope, ->(year, x, y) {joins(:performance_stats).where(performance_stats: {year: year}.where.not(x => y)}
```

Then you can use it everywhere like below:

```rb
School.my_awesome_scope(year, x.to_sym, y)
```

or even: `School.where(...).my_awesome_scope(year, x.to_sym, y)`

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you! I have not worked with scopes before. A note for others who are being introduced to scopes: you have to restart your console when you make changes to your scope. This is the working code: scope :my_awesome scope, ->(year, x, y) {joins(:performance_stats).where(performance_stats: {year: year}).where.not(performance_stats: {x => y})}